# Concurrency in non-blocking socket?

Tags: c, sockets, queue, nonblocking

## Context :

Linux debian 64.
I am self learning how sockets work and it is very interesting.
Single threaded application.

## Question :

I am not in the clear with an async/non-blocking question. The socket is set up with 
fcntl(s, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

1) What exactly happens if two connections arrive exactly at the same time on one socket ?

When sockets are non blocking, will the code running the socket (call it reception) read the datas and do others stuffs with it in parallel or sequentially ? (single thread app)

I mean, with a non blocking socket, are the incoming requests treated sequentially but very fast (non-blocking operations so only the network becomes the bottleneck not the cpu) or in parallel ?

I ask because I would like to maintain a stack array in the script and cannot afford race condition when pushing datas into it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Blocking" is very specific term that pertains the scheduler of the operating system: If a user space call *blocks*, then the operating system deschedules the process (or thread) that is making the call. If an operation is *non-blocking*, that means that it won't automatically and voluntarily cause your process to go to sleep if the operation cannot succeed, but instead the call returns immediately with a status indicating that there was nothing to be done. (Of course your process can still be descheduled forcefully by preemption, but that's a separate issue.)

Comment: Does that involves that from two concurrents connections on one non blocking socket, one will return with a -1 and not be treated by the socket code ? If so, how is it different from blocking behavior ?

Comment: @Larry: I don't understand your question. The non-blocking property refers to the functions `read()`, `write()`, `connect()` etc. A `read()` called on a non-blocking file descriptor will not block, whereas on a blocking file descriptor it may block.

Comment: Ok, so if I have two incoming requests at the same time, they will be read in parallel ? Meaning that if I keep track of an array there will be problems when accessing it (race condition)?

Comment: @Larry: No, there are no problems. You cannot observe a "time" at which anything arrives. That's not a physical property of your system. All you can do is call `read()` or `accept()` etc., in sequence. Accepting connections will happen in some arbitrary order, which is the *only* behaviour your program can observe. (All the available data is queued up internally at the file descriptor by the kernel.)

Comment: "All the available data is queued up internally at the file descriptor by the kernel" That is exactly what I hoped to read ! Many thanks Kerrek